# How to multiply two $n×n$ matrices by efficient method?

Tags: matrices

We need to carry out $2(n^3)-(n^2)$ number of basic operations (like addition and multiplication) to multiply two $n×n$ matrices. Is there any other efficient way so that we could use less no. of operations to multiply them?

Comment: There have been a lot of progress on this starting with the algorithm of Volker Strassen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith–Winograd_algorithm

Comment: But Strassen method is for 2×2 right?

Answer (score 2):

The method you described is $O(n^3)$, using [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Algorithms do exist that have sub-cubic runtimes.

This [Wikipedia section summarizes the history and current state of those algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Sub-cubic_algorithms) quite nicely.

> The current $O(n^k)$ algorithm with the lowest known exponent $k$ is a generalization of the [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) that has an asymptotic complexity of $O(n^{2.3728639})$, by François Le Gall.